# В чем проблема?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    echo "<textarea name="mess" rows="3" cols="60">'$name'</textarea>";
?>
```

Comment: Вам подсветка ответила)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так:

```
echo '< textarea name="mess" rows="3" cols="60">'.$name.'< /textarea>';
```

Answer (score 2):

> `echo "<textarea name="mess" rows="3" cols="60">'$name'</textarea>";`

Кавычки. Надо так:

```
echo "<textarea name='mess' rows='3' cols='60'>$name</textarea>";
```

Comment: забыли отделить переменную

Comment: Она в двойных кавычках.

Comment: Мне почему-то выносят мозг одинарные кавычки. xml не ругается на них? К слову, может человеку лучше про экранирование рассказать?)

Comment: Нет, не ругается. И причем он тут?  
Можно и про экранирование рассказать, но зачем?

Comment: Ну, типа, на будущее) Например, onclick уже стремно будет писать. А xml - xhtml солиднее как-то. Я не докопаться, я дополнить)

Answer (score 2):

Кроме того, в `echo` можно использовать запятые:

```
echo '<textarea name="mess" rows="3" cols="60>', $_GET["name"], '</textarea>';
```

Плюс желательно [не копировать переменные просто так](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html). В данном примере (не видно, что и как идёт дальше) переменная $name не очень-то и нужна.